# Rails: strip_tags escapes enter key as &#13;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, sanitize

When I press the enter key in the product description the following code from below displays it as:  Is there any way to make it display nothing or a new line?

Example code:

```
<dd><%= truncate(strip_tags(product.description), length: 80, omission: '... %s') % link_to('(more)', product) %></dd>
```

Comment: Are you using an editor in the description field?

Comment: No. Just a simple form with textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's an issue with Rails 4.2: [rails.strip_tags for html with carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896700/rails-strip-tags-for-html-with-carriage-return)

You can use an earlier version of Rails, or combine strip_tags with sanitize:
`sanitize(strip_tags(string))`