# rails.strip_tags for html with carriage return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Following code converts \r to  is it correct?

```
strip_tags "<a>aaa</b>\r\n<!-- aaa -->" # => "aaa&#13;\n"
```

is it correct? 
I supposed to receive

```
"aaa\r\n"
```

Comment: Seems like a bug. \r shouldn't be escaped because browsers recognize EOL in Windows format. It should return result string as you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed there:
https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/issues/31

The reason is related to encoding special characters.

Some related bugs are fixed in Rails 4.2.1

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same issue recently. I've tested on both rails 4.0.12 and 4.2.0, and only saw **aaa&#13\n** on 4.2.0. So I guess it might be an issue in the later version.